# Using the jQuery appear plugin with Knockout

Tags: jquery-plugins, knockout.js

I'm having some trouble integrating the [appear-plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) with my Knockout viewmodel. My first attempt only involved a single appear-item and a single global action but now I have multiple number of items to appear on and multiple action to trigger. I was thinking of making a binding-handler for this purpuse which could be used like this:

```
<div class="loadMoreTrigger" data-bind="appear: loadMore" data-appear-top-offset="200" />
```

My skills with custom bindinghandlers is very limited, and maybee there is existing code for this already? Haven't found any...

Would this be possible at all? And the right way of doing it? (I'm trying to lazy load items)

This is what I have now:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.appear = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).appear();
        var action = valueAccessor();
        $(element).on("appear", action);
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: I found the problem. The appearing elements was inside scroll-divs and Appear only checks for visibility when the documents scroll/resize is triggered. I had to listen (and throttle) for scroll in the parent-div as well. But then again I choose a custom solution in the end anyway. No need for Appear in my case.